# Startup bean not called

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I created a Java Web Application Project in NetBeans, and created a startup bean in it:

```
package malibu.util;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@javax.ejb.Startup
public class Startup {
    @EJB
    private ProviderEJB providerEJB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() {
        System.err.println("Initialization success.");
    }
}
```

But the code is not called after I deploy the application. What can cause this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following set of annotations:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class Startup {
    @EJB
    private ProviderEJB providerEJB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onStartup() {
        System.err.println("Initialization success.");
    }
}
```

You will find more details [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/a_sampling_of_ejb_3) and in [this book](http://www.packtpub.com/ejb-3-1-cookbook/book) (chapter 2).

Answer (score 7):

The Startup annotation is for usage with Singleton beans, not with stateless beans. See the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html).

Also, @LocalBean is not needed in this case. This declares that you want an additional no-interface view, but this is only needed if the bean implements a remote or local business interface. If you omit it you get a no-interface view by default.

Answer (score 1):

In my case JBoss 7EAP required the ejb-jar.xml config file on the war to load the @Startup EJB .

```
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
           version="3.1">
 <enterprise-beans>...</enterprise-beans></jboss:ejb-jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Startup.html

Mark a **singleton** bean for eager initialization during the application startup sequence.